# Joint Cumulative Distribution Function for $X\sim \exp( \lambda)$ and $Y=X^3$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Given $X\sim \exp(\lambda)$ and $Y = X^3$, what would be their joint cumulative distribution, $F(x, y)$? Since $X$ and $Y$ are dependent, I can't just integrate the product of their probability density functions: $f(x)f(y)$.
I've got it down to:

$\begin{align*}
F(x,y)
&= P(X \le x, Y \le y) \\
&= P(X \le x, X^3 \le y) \\
&= P(X \le x, X \le y^{1/3}) \\
&= P(X \le \min(x, y^{1/3}))
\end{align*}$

but don't know how to proceed from here on.
I've determined the probability density functions for f(x) and f(y). 
If they were independent, I would just integrate f(y)f(x) dx dy
Since they are not independent, I'm not sure how to derive their joint probability distribution. Once I have that, my assumption is that I can just integrate that to derive their joint cdf.

[image]

Comment: The joint CDF needs to be specified for all $(x,y)$. It is obviously $0$ in the second, third and fourth quadrants. For the first quadrant, try finding $F_{X,Y}(x_0,y)$ for fixed $x_0 > 0$ as $y$ varies from $0$ to $\infty$.

Comment: @dfeuer Thanks for re-editing the question, which made no sense just a minute or so ago!

Comment: @DilipSarwate, I felt responsible! I voted to approve the edit and then immediately realized it was bogus.

Comment: Hi Dilip,thank you for your response. I've determined the individual probability density functions for X and Y. Specifically, my difficulty is with:

Comment: 1) figuring out how to derive the joint pdf

Comment: 2) what the limits of the integrals should be

Comment: Hi Graphth, thank you for your answer. I could kick myself for forgetting about splitting up the cases. That clears things up.

Comment: Hi wolfies, it clears up my question on the limits of the integrals. However it leaves me with the question of how to determine the joint probability density function that I need to derive the joint cumulative distribution function. Is your comment meant to indicate that I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Break it up into cases.  Case 1, $0 \leq x \leq y^{1/3}$.  Case 2, $0 \leq y^{1/3} < x$.